# Jquery bootstrap multiselect Issue - duplicating the dropdown

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am using the [jquery and bootstrap plugin](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)  in asp.net mvc.
The issue is that the dropdown with checkboxes is rendering separately from the normal dropdown.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => Model.DepDashTaskLists[i].BusinessRuleQuestion1Answer, new MultiSelectList(slh.GetRegistrationAnswerLookup(Model.DepDashTaskLists[i].BusinessRuleQuestion1), "Value", "Text", Model.DepDashTaskLists[i].BusinessRuleAnswers), new {  @id = "RuleQuestionListBoxAnswer", @class = "listbox", @rows = "2", @columns = "7", @height="6" })
```

Javascript

```
    $('.listbox').multiselect({
         
            buttonClass: '',
            templates: {
 button: '<span style="margin-bottom: 3px" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Options </span>'
            },
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Ideally I would like the checkbox dropdown to be triggered and placed inside the listbox and disable the regular dropdown

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) multiselect?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes